# How to create a sails.js app that will listen on two different ports simultaneously

Tags: node.js, ssl, express, sails.js, ports

For example, I have a sails.js application that (by default) listens on port 1337.  I want to configure it to listen on two different ports at the same time - one for SSL and one for non-SSL traffic.  Is this even possible?  I have scoured the documentation and cannot find an example that shows me anything other than setting a single port value.

Do I have to create an front-end that (like Apache or nginx) to do it is it it possible to stick with a pure node.js solution - perhaps with express?

I should add that I am only using the server for web sockets via socket.io

A working example would be great, but any tips and pointers would help.

Comment: Maybe your are looking for [node-http-proxy](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy)?

Comment: I have used that before and will have another poke around with it - but the "two instances" approach using environment variables looks favourite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the simplest would probably be to run your server twice.

Just make sure you share common data like sessions and persistent global variables - maybe using something like redis (sails can automatically base your session on redis and can even bind a model on the redis server while keeping the rest on your current database)

Comment: I could do that I guess. I know you can dictate the port on the command line, but it seems trickier to make one use SSL and the other not. As far as I know that is dictated by the config that both instances will share. I could start one as production and one as development and split the config that way - but not ideal, especially as on the IBMi server I am using grunt just seems to time out no matter how long I allow it.

Comment: yes you would need more than the port, and I don't think the right way would be to put that on the command line anyway.

environment variables make more sense to me (eg INSTANCE=https ), you then use your environment variable in the config file to switch values